Nvidia not working after restart (wrong driver installing)
After a restart I realized my Nvidia doesn't work (v495). Possibly due to Linux/Ubuntu upgrade at some point (I tend to leave my laptop on for days and weeks).
I uninstalled everything and trying to install afresh but when I e.g. do sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-495 it seems it tries to forcefully install other unrelated Nvidia versions too:
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dctrl-tools dkms nvidia-dkms-510 nvidia-dkms-535 nvidia-firmware-535-535.171.04 nvidia-kernel-common-535 nvidia-kernel-source-535
Suggested packages:
  debtags
The following NEW packages will be installed
  dctrl-tools dkms nvidia-dkms-495 nvidia-dkms-510 nvidia-dkms-535 nvidia-firmware-535-535.171.04

How can I just install 495 without the 5xx stuff? Since 5xx does not work on my laptop (XPS 15) from previous experience.
